# Different Conceptions of Z

Tags: soft-question, big-list

To the algebraist, $\mathbb{Z}$ is just the free group with one generator. To the algebraic topologist, $\mathbb{Z}$ is just the fundamental group of the circle. To be glib, what do $\mathbb{Z}$ mean to you?

Comment: He he: everyone's answering the _wrong_ question!  When translated into English, the question reads "To be glib, what do _the integers_ mean to you?".

Comment: Why I don't like this question: (1) $\mathbb Z$ is not "just" anything.  An "algebraist" very well might study "rings and algebras", for example.  (2) It's discussion-y.  How are you going to pick a "right" answer?

Comment: I'm not sure how appropriate this is to MathOverflow, but I've certainly wondered the same thing and I'm interested in seeing people's answers.

Comment: I agree with Theo. I don't really see what you expect to get out of asking this question. I don't like any of the answers, and it's hard to imagine somebody giving a good one.

Answer (score 5):

Initial object in the category of commutative rings.

Comment: (Or the category of rings.)

Comment: (Or the category of Z-algebras)

Answer (score 3):

To a number theorist, shouldn't $\mathbb Z$ be the world?

Answer (score 1):

Final object in the category of schemes.

Answer (score -1):

Just $\mathbb{Z}$ ? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

An infinite discrete subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: From the coarse geometry perspective, it _is_ R!